# How to read table-like file into multiple arrays (bash)

Tags: bash

If I have a file example1.txt containing multiple strings

```
str1
str2
str3
...
```

I can read them into a bash array by using

```
mapfile -t mystrings < example1.txt.
```

Now say my file example2.txt is formatted as a table

```
str11 str12 str13
str21 str22 str23
str31 str32 str33
...   ...   ...
```

and I want to read each column into a different array. I know I can use other tools such as awk to separate each line into fields. Is there some way to combine this functionality with mapfile? I'm looking for something like

```
mapfile -t firstcol < $(cat example2.txt | awk '//{printf $1"\n"}')
mapfile -t secondcol < $(cat example2.txt | awk '//{printf $2"\n"}')
```

(which doesn't work).

Any other suggestion on how to handle a table in bash is also welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading each *row* is simple, so let's build off that. I'll assume you have a proper matrix (i.e., each row has the same number of columns. This will be much easier since you are using `bash` 4.3.

```
while read -a row; do
    c=0
    for value in "${row[@]}"; do
        declare -n column=column_$(( c++ ))
        column+=( "$value" )
    done
done < table.txt
```

There! Now, did it work?

```
$ echo "${column_0[@]}"
str11 str21 str31 
$ echo "${column_1[@]}"
str12 str22 str32
```

I think so!

`declare -n` makes a *nameref* to an array (implicitly declared by the `+=` on the next line) using a counter that increments as we iterate over each row. Then we simply append the current column value to the array behind the current nameref.

Comment: This is almost the approach I went with myself (didn't yet have the answer on which version to target when I chose something different).

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `process substitution` like this:

```
mapfile -t firstcol < <(awk '{print $1}' example2.txt)

mapfile -t secondcol < <(awk '{print $2}' example2.txt)

mapfile -t thirdcol < <(awk '{print $3}' example2.txt)
```

Comment: This is like: taking the stdout of awk and forwarding to stdin of mapfile? Like a pipe?

Comment: Seems quite inefficient to be reading the file once per column rather than doing a single pass.

Comment: @mbrandalero: `process substitution` acts like a file and avoids creating temporary files. @Charles: Yes, if there are large number of columns then yes it will involve running awk that many times. My answer was focussing to fix the problem in OP's attempt of `mapfile` with `awk`.

Comment: @mbrandalero, if you did a pipe from `awk` to `mapfile`, the data would be lost when the subshell running `mapfile` on the right-hand side of the pipeline exited. Thus, using this idiom is necessary.

Comment: Unless the file is huge, this is probably a good tradeoff for versions prior to 4.3. Getting my approach to work without namerefs is a bit tedious.

Comment: Thanks for the useful explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Something like this, perhaps?

```
readarrays() {
  declare -a values
  declare idx line=0
  while read -a values; do
    for idx in "${!values[@]}"; do
      [[ ${@:idx+1:1} ]] || break
      declare -g "${@:idx+1:1}[$line]=${values[@]:idx:1}"
    done
    (( ++line ))
  done
}
```

Tested as:

```
bash4-4.3$ (readarrays one two three <<<$'a b c\nd e f'; declare -p one two three)
declare -a one='([0]="a" [1]="d")'
declare -a two='([0]="b" [1]="e")'
declare -a three='([0]="c" [1]="f")'
```