# How to save multiple columns to bash arrays with 1 select in mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I'm trying to save multiple columns in bash arrays with one query, but I can't figure it out.
Now I have 3 SELECTs like this:

```
read -d \t -ra data1<<< $(mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT data1 FROM users_logs')
read -d \t -ra data2<<< $(mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT data2 FROM users_logs')
read -d \t -ra data3<<< $(mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT data3 FROM users_logs')
```

and it's working, but I wonder, if this is an optimal way. I think that I could achieve this with one query.
I was trying to do something with `mysql --batch` and `mapfile`, but couldn't make it.

and output of running:

```
mysql -u root -p'password' -D'users_info' -se 'SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM users_logs'
```

is:

```
somemail1@gmail.com 2 2z7bhxb55d3
somemail2@gmail.com 2 we3cq3micu9cn
somemail3@gmail.com 1 we3cq1dicu9cn
```

All those data are varchar(30).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the objective is to read a grid of data into multiple arrays (with each column being loaded into a separate array) ...

For dynamically generating/populating arrays using `bash namerefs` take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32279483).

If the number of arrays (and their names) are predefined ...

First some data to simulate the OP's output:

```
$ cat mysql.out
somemail1@gmail.com 2 2z7bhxb55d3
somemail2@gmail.com 2 we3cq3micu9cn
somemail3@gmail.com 1 we3cq1dicu9cn
```

**NOTE:** The following code assumes the column *data* does not include white space, eg, the above file has 3 columns and not 1 column with embedded spaces; otherwise OP will need to insure the stream of input has a well-defined column delimiter that can be used by the `while` loop

One `bash` loop idea:

```
unset      data1 data2 data3
typeset -a data1 data2 data3

i=0
while read -r col1 col2 col3
do
    (( i++ ))
    data1[${i}]="${col1}"
    data2[${i}]="${col2}"
    data3[${i}]="${col3}"
done < mysql.out                                     # replace this with ...
# done < <(mysql ... SELECT data1,data2,data3 ...)   # this to have mysql results fed directly into 'while' loop
```

This gives us:

```
$ typeset -p data1 data2 data3
declare -a data1=([1]="somemail1@gmail.com" [2]="somemail2@gmail.com" [3]="somemail3@gmail.com")
declare -a data2=([1]="2" [2]="2" [3]="1")
declare -a data3=([1]="2z7bhxb55d3" [2]="we3cq3micu9cn" [3]="we3cq1dicu9cn")
```

---

If you don't mind the indices starting @ 0 ...

```
unset      data1 data2 data3
typeset -a data1 data2 data3

while read -r col1 col2 col3
do
    data1+=("${col1}")
    data2+=("${col2}")
    data3+=("${col3}")
done < mysql.out
```

This gives us:

```
$ typeset -p data1 data2 data3
declare -a data1=([0]="somemail1@gmail.com" [1]="somemail2@gmail.com" [2]="somemail3@gmail.com")
declare -a data2=([0]="2" [1]="2" [2]="1")
declare -a data3=([0]="2z7bhxb55d3" [1]="we3cq3micu9cn" [2]="we3cq1dicu9cn")
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!